# Trying to Determine if an Optimal Solution from an LP Solver is Indeed Optimal

Tags: linear-programming

Suppose we have the following LP problem:
$$min\ C^Tx $$
$$s.t. \ Ax = b $$
$$x>=0$$

I am trying to confirm that an optimal solution $x^*$ obtained from an LP solver for such a problem is optimal. To do so, I am calculating the reduced cost and checking it is non-negative. 
$$Reduced \ cost = C-\pi A$$
$$where \ \pi = C_bB$$
$ C_b$: entries in C corresponding to the basic optimal variables

$B$: the optimal basis (i.e., columns form A corresponding to the basic optimal variables)

As you see, to construct the basis matrix $B$, the basic optimal variables need to be identified. I am identifying the basic optimal variables as those variables in $x^*$ that are $ > 0$.
The issue is that sometimes, variables in $x^*$ that are $ > 0 $ are less than the needed number of basic variables (the needed number of basic variables is the number of constraints in the problem). Hence, some basic optimal variables $= 0$ in the optimal solution which indicates degeneracy. In this case, how can I build the matrix B to confirm optimality? Can I arbitrary chose any variable and consider it as a basic optimal variable?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the dual of this LP? if the "solution" you got from LP is possible in the dual problem then it is the optimum.

Comment: Thank you @MoonKnight for your comment. 
To find if the dual problem is possible (i.e., feasible), you need to calculate the optimal dual variables which are the variable $\pi$ in my question above. Hence, the same issue is faced.